# syntax for returning reference in C++ - the ampersand

Tags: c++, return-type

We're all familiar with returning by reference:

```
//global 
int x;

int& getElX()
{
    return x;
}
```

Because the function is returning type of `int &`, why don't you have to say `return (int&)X`?

*Again, I understand how return-by-reference works. This is a question mostly on syntax*

Furthermore, does the meaning change if you do `return (int&)x`?

Comment: It should be,
int& getElx(int x, vector<int> &v)
you are returning a reference to local variable. Here vector<int> v is local and will be destroyed after the call finishes. And v[x] will be destroyed etc.

Comment: First, you do not understand how return by reference works. Second, you are returning a reference to local parameter, which is undefined behavior.

Comment: Yes I know. I fixed it.

Comment: @Adrian: Can you clarify why you think the cast is required?  `v[x]` is already an `int&`, why would you need a cast?

Comment: @MooingDuck it's an int. Anyway I could rewrite my example to have it return a global int.

Comment: @Adrian No, it's `int&`. Check your facts (or the answers).

Comment: I changed the function so it's just returning a global `int`

Comment: No you didn't. It's returning an `int&` bound to an undeclared variable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`int&` can bind to an lvalue of type `int`. If the expression returned is already an lvalue of type `int`, then no cast is required. If the expression returned were of some other type that could not be directly used to initialize an `int&`, then the cast would be required.

The meaning does not change with `(int&)v[x]`: since the operand of the cast is already an lvalue of type `int`, the cast has no effect.

Answer (score 4):

The expression `v[x]` is equivalent to `v.operator[](x)`, which calls the function `vector<int>::reference vector<int>::operator[](size_t)`, now `vector<int>::reference` is a typedef to `int&`. A function call expression of a function returning type ‘lvalue-reference to int’ is an ‘lvalue expression of type int’. 
The statetment `return v[x]` initialises the return value of the function with the expression `v[x]`, the return type is ‘lvalue-reference to int’, an lvalue-reference may only be initialised with an lvalue expression of a compatible type, which `v[x]` is. Now the expression `(int&)v[x]` casts `v[x]` to an ‘lvalue of type int’ which it already is, so it does nothing.

Note: the lifetime of the reference entity returned by `vector<int>::operator[](size)` is at most the lifetime of vector it is called on, (before you made your edit) this was the lifetime of the parameter `v` which was from the start of execution of the function until it's end, which occurs upon execution of the `return` statetment. And so the referenced entity returned by your function has already expired, which means accessing it is undefined (i.e. do not do this).

Answer (score -1):

For the same reason that you do not have to write:

```
int x = 2;
int& ref = (int&)x;
```

Comment: And what is that reason?

Comment: @Adrian: Why is the sky blue? Why would you need this cast? It's pointless. You're already initialising an `int&` from `x`. Why would you need _two_ "conversions" instead of just one?

Comment: My point here is that (more or less) the same initialisation syntax/rules are used for initialising your returned `int&` as they would be for a bog-standard `int&` declaration. If you want to know why all of C++'s declaration rules are the way they are, that's a very broad topic with no real answer.

Comment: and that is the question. It was answered.

Comment: @Adrian: I disagree.